# Loading file contains using document ready function not working

Tags: javascript, java, php, jquery

I would like to load the following page inside another page after the main page has loaded. I have the following code:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('http://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]/X.php?logon=Y&vendorref="<?php .$row_RS_Product['id'].?>"&mode=product', function(data) {
            $('#tabs-6').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am not very familiar with this code so please excuse me if I made the obvious mistake
Could anybody help please as it does work when using `file_get_contents` in php, but this is slowing the page load down tremendous.
Any help welcome

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if the request works? If the URL is on a different domain you may be being blocked by the Same Origin Policy

Comment: @Roy Thanks for your reply the URL is on the same domain and it does work when using the php method, I just want to delay loading it until the main page is loaded which is not working for me

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I have a syntax error in the code somewhere but I'm not sure how to find out what is wrong, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to get `$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]` from PHP so you need to add `<?php echo` when creating the url to get from. Also you need to have `echo` when opening the php tag to echo, not `.` .
Dot is used to concat string in php like this `"aaa" . "bbb"` (without opening the php tag)

So you need something like this:

```
$.get('http://<?php echo $_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]; ?>/X.php?logon=Y&vendorref="<?php echo $row_RS_Product['id']; ?>"&mode=product', function(data) {
        $('#tabs-6').html(data);
    });
```

Comment: I can't see any errors, it is just not displaying the content

Comment: Check the network tab and see if there is any request to your url, if the url is correct and click on that request and in preview tab you can see the result.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help , you've solved it there were a few bits wrong with the url request like leaving in a ";". Thanks again so much, you've made my day